# Number of fixed point free permutations by groupoid cardinals

Tags: category-theory, groupoids, derangements

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) that the number $D_n$ of derangements (fixed point free permutations) on a set of $n$ elements is exactly $\left[\dfrac{n!}e\right]$, the closest integer number to $\dfrac{n!}e$.

Using [groupoid cardinality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid+cardinality), one assigns exactly $e=\sum\limits_n\frac1{n!}$ as the cardinality of the (skeleton of the) category of finite sets.

Is there any deeper heurusistic (or even a clear proof) of the above formula for the number of derangements in the context of groupoid cardinalities?

Comment: Have you seen John Baez's recent series of blog posts about random permutations on the $n$-Category Café ? I haven't read them in details but it seems closely related.